# How to Move or Swap this text in Notepad or Word or in Google Docs

Tags: ms-word, google-docs, text-editor, notepad

The format of the text is in this type. A word followed with hypen and with URL. How to move or swap text in Notepad or Word or Google Docs File so that the format will be URL followed by hypen and word.

Actual Format is

```
Google - https://www.google.com/   
Bing - https://www.bing.com/  
Yahoo - https://www.yahoo.com/  
Ask - https://www.ask.com/  
AOL - https://www.aol.com/  
Baidu - https://www.baidu.com/
```

Expected Format is

```
https://www.google.com/ - Google  
https://www.bing.com/ - Bing  
https://www.yahoo.com/ - Yahoo  
https://www.ask.com/ - Ask  
https://www.aol.com/ - AOL  
https://www.baidu.com/ - Baidu
```

Comment: Notepad ot Notepad++ ?

Comment: Notepad or Word or Google Docs

Answer (score 0):

**In Notepad++**

You can use regular expression search mode to find and replace to get the expected output format.

```
Find What: (^.*)-(.*?$)
Replace With: \2 - \1
```

Capture two groups seperated by `-` then replace the order

**In Google Document**

Instead of using the built-in find and replace function use [Google Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/)

```
function myFunction() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var paragraphs = body.getParagraphs();
  for (var i=0; i<paragraphs.length; i++) {
    var text = paragraphs[i].getText();
    paragraphs[i].replaceText(".*", 
       text.replace(/(^.*)-(.*?$)\s*/gi, '$2 - $1') );
  }
}
```

To add google apps script to your google document

- On your Google doc, Go to Tools > Script Editor
- Opens a new tab at https://script.google.com/xxxxxx
- In the Code.gs file enter the script above
- Then hit Run

Comment: Looks interesting, but can you explain how to add this code in google doc and check it.

Comment: After running the script, the document is showing only the "hypens" vertically without any text change 
  -  
  -  
  -  
  -

Comment: By running the above script, both the Before and After HYPEN text got deleted and showing only the HYPENS one by one in the document.

Comment: Updated my code, apparently it should be `$2 - $1` rather than `\2 - \1` to capture groups

Comment: @Tim if this has helped you, make sure to accept it as an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Google Docs you can use the [`REGEXREPLACE` formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245) and fill down :

```
 = REGEXREPLACE(A1, "(\S*) - (\S*).*", "$2 - $1")
```